# Proxmox vmbr0 bridge is not "switching". Why?

Tags: proxmox

I am trying to figure out why the "default" Proxmox network configuration is not behaving as I expect.

I have:

- a Proxmox server (10.0.40.10)
- the network bridge (vmbr0) created by Proxmox by default
- a VM (10.0.40.20) connected to vmbr0 (let's call it VM1)
- a VM (10.0.40.25) connected to vmbr0 (let's call it VM2)
- a gateway (10.0.40.254) configured on vmbr0

When I performed an HTTP transfer (GET) *on* VM2 *from* VM1, the speed I observed indicated that traffic was exiting the Proxmox host, going to the gateway, and returning back to the Proxmox host.

Both VM1 and VM2 are connected to *vmbr0*, so my expectation was that *vmbr0* would "switch" between the two VMs, based on the MAC/ARP, and that the traffic would remain entirely local (and be one or two orders of magnitude faster).

When I run a ping from VM2 to VM1, I observe this:

```
[root@vm2 ~]# ping -c 5 10.0.40.20
PING 10.0.40.20 (10.0.40.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.40.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.485 ms
From 10.0.40.254 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.0.40.20)
64 bytes from 10.0.40.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.609 ms
From 10.0.40.254 icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.0.40.20)
64 bytes from 10.0.40.20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.598 ms

--- 10.0.40.20 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, +2 errors, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.485/0.564/0.609/0.056 ms
```

Running a traceroute shows:

```
[root@vm2 ~]# traceroute -I 10.0.40.20
traceroute to 10.0.40.20 (10.0.40.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (10.0.40.254)  0.328 ms  0.308 ms  0.393 ms
 2  10.0.40.20 (10.0.40.20)  0.472 ms  0.481 ms  0.533 ms
```

The vmbr0 configuration looks like this:

[image: vmbr0]

Network definition for VM1:

[image: vm1]

Network definition for VM2:

[image: vm2]

This seems like such a fundamental use-case it seems like I must be missing something.

Does anyone know if my expectations are correct, or is this correct behavior for vmbr0?  Does something look misconfigured?  Do I need something like Proxy ARP or an on-box virtual router to solve such a simple use-case?

Answer (score 3):

Solved: The IP addresses of some of the Virtual Machines were configured as /32 rather than /24, eg. 10.0.40.25/32 instead of 10.0.40.25/24, and therefore did not consider themselves in the same subnet as their peers, and traffic was sent out on the default route.